# How to check if selected date is between start and end?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, pdo

The following query displays the `name` of the events when the date `start` and `$selected` are the same. format is `2013-07-30` after "removing" time.

However, I want to make use of the `end` field also, and check if the `$selected` date is between `start` and `end` and not only if it equals to `start` as it is now.

Example: `start` : 2013-07-28, `end` : 2013-07-31, `$selected` = 2013-07-30

`$selected` is between `start` and `end` so it is ok to display the name (and other info).

```
$sh = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM events WHERE DATE(`start`) = DATE(:start)');
$sh->bindValue(":start", $selected);
$sh->execute();

while($row1 = $sh->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo $row1['name']; 
}
```

Comment: What about `BETWEEN `

Comment: @PrasanthBendra I know it is between, however I do not know how to implement it to the PDO

Answer (score 4):

you can use `BETWEEN` or :  `< end time` and `> start time`.  try this

```
   SELECT * FROM events WHERE  DATE(:start) Between DATE(`start`) and DATE(`end`)
```

Comment: Works great, thank you. One last thing though, I added AND `city` == 1 at the end of your question  to show the results only form city with number 1, without luck. Am i missing something ?

Comment: you welcome.:).yes you should use it like that `AND city = 1`